# Como iniciar ZooKeeper Command Line Interface?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, hadoop, hbase, zookeeper

Quiero implementar una base de datos hbase y he visto que necesito ZooKeeper. Seguí [el tutorial de tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_installation.htm) pero cuando intento iniciar ZooKeeper Command Line Interface (CLI) obtuve el siguiente error :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/zookeeper-3.4.10$ ./bin/zkCli.sh
Connecting to localhost:2181
2017-12-04 12:57:29,539 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f, built on 03/23/2017 10:13 GMT
2017-12-04 12:57:29,543 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:host.name=mike-thinks
2017-12-04 12:57:29,543 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_151
2017-12-04 12:57:29,545 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2017-12-04 12:57:29,546 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
2017-12-04 12:57:29,546 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../build/classes:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/../conf:
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.name=Linux
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:os.version=4.10.0-40-generic
2017-12-04 12:57:29,547 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.name=mike
2017-12-04 12:57:29,548 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.home=/home/mike
2017-12-04 12:57:29,548 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:user.dir=/home/mike/zookeeper-3.4.10
2017-12-04 12:57:29,549 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@438] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain$MyWatcher@1a86f2f1
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
2017-12-04 12:57:29,574 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1032] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
JLine support is enabled
2017-12-04 12:57:29,652 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1162] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0] 2017-12-04 12:57:30,758 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1032] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-12-04 12:57:30,759 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1162] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar confirma que tienes ZooKeeper corriendo, esto puedes hacerlo lanzando el comando `ruok` con netcat:

```
echo ruok|nc localhost 2181
```

Si esto no te responde, prueba a parar el firewall y descartar esta causa externa de error.

Adicionalmente, prueba a revisar el fichero de configuración `zoo.cfg` que debes encontrar en la ruta `$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/conf`, es posible que hayamos escrito mal la ip a la que nos vinculamos o algún dato similar.